# i need to display max value of each column in my dataframe, also in case of object column i need max object according to the max length in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, object

**Here is my code, which prints max and min value for int and float, so i want to do same the for object, where it should print max, min col value based on object length.**

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(P1-UK-Bank-Customers.csv")

for col in df.select_dtypes([np.int8, np.int16, np.int32, np.int64, np.float]):

```
print('column: ', col)
print('max: ',df[col].max())
print('min: ',df[col].min())
print()**
```

This is my dataframe, which i have given as a csv file.(**NOTE: code should work for any file given**)

```
Customer_ID   Name       Age    Balance

     001      monsi      21     113810.15

     002      minejash   34     36919.73
```

**My expected output is:**

**Customer_ID :**
max: 002
min: 001

**Name:**
max: minejash
min: monsi

**Age:**
max: 34
min: 21

**Balance:**
max: 113810.15
min: 36919.73